# Xamarin Android ReadOnlyStream buffer is too small when reading

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to perform a very simple operation - file download from the internet (in Xamarin.Forms). The file is large, so I am reading it from the stream (which is `ReadOnlyStream`) and writing it to the `FileStream`. Setting a larger buffer size when downloading a big file is desirable because the download process will be faster. What I have noticed, is that actual read buffer is capped just at 8 kB, making the download process painfully slow. Is it a known limitation or a bug? Is there any workaround? My sample code is

```
var url = @"https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var s = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
        var fs = new FileStream(
            Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "myfile"), FileMode.Create);
        var got = 0;
        var total = 0L;
        var buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        while ((got = await s.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"<||> {got}\t|\t{total}");
            total += got;
            await fs.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, got);
        }
```

Same code works as expected on iOS.

EDIT:
It feels like its an issue with HttpClient implementation. You can set it in Android project properties. The recommended one (Android) has this 8 kB cap, while Managed has 16 kB, still too small.

EDIT2:
Using `HttpClient.SendAsync` to download the file "fixes" the speed issue. However, it's not possible to use it with big files, because everything is loaded into memory first.

EDIT3:
Going platform specific also does not help. Same 8192 Bytes cap.

```
public async Task Download(string urlString)
    {
        int count;
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection = url.OpenConnection();
            await connection.ConnectAsync();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.OpenStream(),1024*1024);

            var output = new MemoryStream();

            var data = new byte[1024 * 1024];

            while ((count = await input.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length)) != -1)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"<||> {count}");
                await output.WriteAsync(data, 0, count);
            }

            await output.FlushAsync();

            output.Close();
            input.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"<||> {e}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried [`Stream.CopyToAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync?view=netcore-3.1)? It will handle everything for you.

Comment: I have tried it with my real, more complex app... While I cannot say what was the buffer cap with that, it still was too low taking into account the download time. Also, as far as I understand, Stream.CopyToAsync just include pretty much similar loop like in my example (with some extra code, like setting the stream's position at the end, if I am not mistaken). Thus, I am not sure why it should be different.

Comment: Yes, it will be similar, but it was to discard a problem with .net. Have you tried with other device? It seems to me some restriction in Android or your device.

Comment: I have a Google Pixel 3a... with vanilla android. I have tried with other emulators only, do not have other devices.

Comment: Do happen the same in the emulator?

Comment: Yes, same issue in the emulator of different device

Comment: I've been testing in my device, yep, something in Android restricts the buffer to 8Kb. If you change the `HttpClient` implementation to managed (project options->Android options->Advanced) it increases to 16Kb, is not as much as you wanted but at least it downloads faster... Also, consider using the Android's download manager, it's intended for large downloads so I bet you it will not restrict it's buffer.